# Any connection between Genesis 1:2 and Psalm 42:7: deep calls to deep?

Tags: genesis, psalms

> King James Bible Psalm  Genesis 1:2
> And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the **deep**. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the **waters**.

> King James Bible Psalm 42:7
> **Deep** calleth unto **deep** at the noise of thy **waterspouts**: all thy waves and thy billows are gone over me.

Comment: Why would you think there is a connection ? Just the repeat of a word in scripture is a repeat of meaning, but one cannot assume a definite association of contexts.

Answer (score 4):

This morning I was reading Psalm 42 and came across the expression "deep calls to deep" in verse 7 and I wondered what that meant.

I noticed that whereas the King James Version said "Deep calls to deep at the noise of thy waterspouts", the NLT says "I hear the tumult of the raging seas as your waves and surging tides sweep over me". The dictionary definition of a waterspout is "a rotating column of water and spray formed by a whirlwind occurring over the sea or other body of water".

Here is what I learned when looking into the meaning behind Psalm 42:7.

Psalm 42:7 was cross-referenced to Genesis 1:2 which speaks of the darkness over the surface of the deep and how the Spirit of God was hovering over the waters.

This, in turn, was cross-referenced to Genesis 1:7-8 which describes how God made an expanse to separate the waters under from the waters above.

Then we have Genesis 7:11 which is about the flood where "all the springs ofthe great deep burst forth and the floodgates of the heavens were opened".

In the verses leading up to the statement that “deep calls to deep,” the psalmist says he has been thirsting for the presence of God like a deer panting for streams of water (Psalm 42:1). He portrays his distress figuratively: it’s as if waves and breakers are sweeping over him. Trouble was surging, with one overwhelming swell coming after another. The “deep” trials he faced kept coming, wave-like—deep after deep.

***Conclusion:*** It is my understanding that the Hebrew word translated in Psalm 42:7 as “deep” refers to the deepest depths of the sea. This connects with the deep waters in Genesis 1:2 which is about the deep waters covering the earth.

Spiritually, Psalm42:7 suggests that the psalmist is expressing the fact that his soul was in deep need of God. The psalmist calls out from his place of profound need for the unfathomable greatness of God. ***A deep need calls for a deep remedy***.

Answer (score 2):

The connection between Gen 1:2 and Ps 42:7 exists but is tenuous at best.  I note the following:

- There is no connection of context - each verse exists in a quite different context
- Both verses share the word תְּהוֹם = "deep"
- Both share the word עַל = "over"
- Both mention, in different ways, water: Gen 1:2 has water (מַיִם); while Ps 42:7 has waterfalls, waves and billows.

At the same time, there are also differences between these two:

- Gen 1:2 the mood is calm with an expectation of great things about to happen; Ps 42 depicts great turbulence of personal turmoil that the author seeks comfort from God.
- Gen 1:2 the context is darkness and nothing much exists; Ps 42 depicts much action of the created world - day and night pass (V8), water falls over rocks, etc.
- In Gen 1 the focus is the world; Ps 42 the focus is personal.
- In Gen 1 it is God who speaks (and the world is gradually created over 6 days); In Ps 42:7 it is the "deep calling to the deep" that is speaking.

Therefore, while Gen 1:2 and Ps 42:7 share just two words, they appear to be significantly different passages for quite different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one commentary from the Talmud that makes the connection you suggest.  Rashi wrote:

> *Deep calls to deep*: This refers to the deep waters, as in *the deep* [תְּהוֹם] *over which the Spirit of God was hovering* (Genesis 1:2).
> Just as the deeps long for the Spirit of God, so too does the soul of
> a person long for God. And why does the verse say *deep calls to
> deep*? To teach us that just as the deep waters do not cease, but
> continually call out, so too does the soul of a person not cease in
> its longing for God.

---

Other commentaries in the Talmud also associate *the deep* of the Psalm with *the deep* of a human soul, but they do not make the same direct connection to Genesis.  From *Talmud Bavli* (Tractate Ta'anit 7a):

> Rav Huna<sup>2</sup> says: 'What is the meaning of the verse, *Deep calls to deep
> in the roar of your waterfalls; all your waves and breakers have swept
> over me*? **The deep wisdom of God calls out to the deep wisdom within
> human beings**, as it is said, *For there is a spirit in man, and the
> breath of the Almighty gives him understanding'* (Job 32:8).

From *Talmud Yerushalmi* (Berakhot 4:3)

> Rabbi Abba bar Kahana<sup>3</sup> said in the name of Rabbi Yohanan<sup>3</sup>: "What is the
> meaning of the verse, *Deep calls to deep in the roar of your
> waterfalls; all your waves and breakers have swept over me?* **God
> calls out to the depths of a person's heart**, as it is said, *My soul
> thirsts for God, for the living God* (Psalm 42:3). The sound of the
> shofar represents the voice of God calling out to humanity. And the
> waves and breakers that have swept over the speaker in the psalm
> represent the difficulties and obstacles that may prevent a person
> from hearing and responding to God's call."

---

Among Christian commentators, Cyril of Alexandria and Augustine also interpret the *deep* (LXX ἄβυσσος, Lat. *abyssus*) allegorically. Both see the *waterfalls* as meaning the grace of God, and the breakers symbolizing the trials of the world.  Augustine:

> *Deep calls to deep in the roar of your waterfalls; all your waves and breakers have swept over me*. What are these waterfalls and what are
> these waves? The waterfalls are the grace of God. The waves are the
> temptations and trials of this world. But those who drink from the
> waterfalls will not be drowned by the waves. Rather, they will be
> cleansed, refreshed, and strengthened, so that they can overcome the
> trials and tribulations of this life and find their rest in God."
> (*Expositions on the Book of Psalms*, Psalm 42)

and Cyril:

> The *waterfalls* symbolize the abundant and overflowing grace of God,
> which is poured out upon us without measure. And the *waves and
> breakers* represent the trials and tribulations of this world, which
> threaten to overwhelm us. But just as the waterfalls are more powerful
> than the waves, so too is the grace of God more powerful than the
> trials of this world. Through God's grace, we can endure and overcome
> all things, and find our true rest and peace in him. (*Commentary on
> the Psalms*, Psalm 42)

---

John Chrysostom also interpreted the verse allegorically, seeing *waves and breakers* as symbolizing the world, but he interpreted the waterfalls to represent God's word:

> The *waterfalls* represent the power of God's Word, which flows down
> from heaven to nourish and strengthen our souls. And the *waves and
> breakers* represent the trials and tribulations of this world, which
> threaten to overwhelm us. But just as the waterfalls are more powerful
> than the waves, so too is the Word of God more powerful than the
> trials of this world. Through God's Word, we can find the strength and
> courage to overcome all things, and find our true rest and peace in
> him." (*Homilies on the Psalms*, Psalm 42)

---

<sup>1.</sup> <sup>1040-1105 CE, medieval French rabbi, scholar, and commentator</sup>
<sup>2.</sup> <sup>Prominent teacher in the Babylonian Talmud, who lived in the 4th century CE in Babylon (present-day Iraq)</sup>
<sup>3.</sup> <sup>Talmudic sage who lived in Palestine in the 3rd century CE</sup>
<sup>4.</sup> <sup>Also Palestine, 3rd/4th centuries CE</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Actually I believe you are quite right, the Genesis waters in chapter 1 are literal and symbolic of chaos for the ex Hebrew Egyptian slaves who would have understood that plainly. The actual symbol for water in the Hebrew alphabet,men, can paralela mentally mean waters of life or death depending on their context. Considering both the creation story and the use of animal and water reference, plus the dualism of the spirit of Man being downcast (see the story of Cain) and the spirit of God hovering over the waters the psalmist is communicating something about his desire to seek the nurturing and life establishing control of the creator in his caos and need. Interestingly rivers and water springs and hovering mist are part of the paradise state of the garden of Eden in chapter 2 of Genesis and after the fall the earth is cursed in Hebrew meaning hardened or embittered implying a lack of water. The idea of a deer thirsting for water in a dry land envokes up the idea of creation in the wilderness in the fallen and vulnerable state. It isn't until the flood where water falls from heaven during the immense pain and lament of God in chapter 6 where both destruction and salvation are promised for both beast and man. Interesting observations huh.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).